# non-map function definition

Tags: functions

I can not understand the idea of function definition.

[image: Function map example]

Why is this a non-map function?

How I understand this function is surjective but not injektiv. But in the book, the author says that this is not map, and we can skip a step with defining properties.

Comment: The example doesn't qualify to be a function itself, where I am taught, because it doesn't take c anywhere. I suppose that is what the author means by non-map

Comment: And it appears to take $d$ to two different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is *not a function* and *not a map* (these words usually mean the same in this context) for two independent reasons:

- $c$ doesn't map to anything
- $d$ appears to map to both $2$ and $3$

A function must map every element of its domain to *exactly one* element of the codomain.

Comment: So, the function must be aslways injective? Or it should alwayse make some work with all elements from first set? And it can be not injective, but it must have in work all elements

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: No, where would you get that from?

Comment: From my math classes. I have update my comment

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: "Injective" and "surjective" are about how many arrows there are _into_ each element of the _codomain_. But the trouble here is that some elements of the _domain_ have a wrong number of arrows _out of_ them. Every element of the domain must have **exactly one** arrow out of it.

Comment: For example when i have three functions: 1) f: N_0 -> N_0, x->x^2; 2) Z -> Z, x->x^2; 3) R+ -> R+, x->x^2; they are all functions?

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: Yes.